# regular expression for deleting zeros that come immediately after a non-digit

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am writing code to convert numbers counted in thousands (separated in writing in chunks of 3) into myriads (separated in writing in chunks of 4) for Japanese formatting.

the current code produces following results:
ex)
input: `123,456,789,123,456`
output: `123兆4567億8912万3456`
Using regular expressions I have been able to delete sequences of four 0's and the proceding character with `myriad = myriad.replace(/0000\D/g, "");` 
result:
input: `12,300,002,345`
output: `123億2345`  (`0000万` was deleted)

However, the code currently doesn't delete unnessecary zero's:
ex)
input: `32,131,200,232,132`
output: `32兆1312億0023万2132`
(I would like to delete the two zeros before `23万`)

I am trying to find a regex solution to this and have attempted with
 `myriad = myriad.replace(/?=0{1,3}/g, "");` to no avail...  I am rather stumped, any suggestions would be helpful

EDIT:
I think the regex should replace 0's that follow any \D , but I can't figure out how to delete them without deleting the preceding character as well

EDIT: working app:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
   <title>変換天才</title>
   

 <script>
 

 //myriad converter function help from Stack Overflow user paxdiablo
 function makeNum(num) {
    num = num.replace(/,/g,"");      //remove commas
    var markers = "万億兆京該秭穣溝澗正載極";
    var result = "";

 //regroup in myriads
    while (num.length > 4) {
        if (markers.length == 0) {
            result = "(?)" + num.substr(num.length-4) + result;
        } else {
            result = markers.substr(0, 1) + num.substr(num.length-4) + result;
            markers = markers.substr(1);
        }
        num = num.substr(0, num.length-4);
   }
     return num + result;
 }

 //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 // insert commas for readability
 //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 function makeCom(num){

   num = num.replace(/,/g, "");
 
   var result = num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

   return result;

 }

 function convert(){
 
 var innum = document.getElementById("input").value;
 var parsnum = (innum.replace(/,/g,""));
 if (isNaN(parseInt(parsnum)) == true) {
 document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = "Please enter valid number.";

 }
 else {
 var myriad = makeNum(innum);

 // delete unnec. zeros 
 myriad = myriad.replace(/0000\D/g, "");
 myriad = myriad.replace(/(\D)0+/g, "$1");
 document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = myriad ;
 
 //display number with commas
 var commanum = makeCom(innum);
 document.getElementById("commaed").innerHTML = "You entered: " + commanum ;
 
   }
 }

 
 
 //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 // button functions
 //xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 
 function multiplier(kake) {
  var mult = document.getElementById("input").value;
 
   if (mult == "") {
    mult = kake;
  }

   else if (isNaN(mult)==false){
    mult = (mult * kake);
  }

   else {
    document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = "Please enter valid number";
    return;
  }

   document.getElementById("input").value = mult; 
 }


 function thou(){
  multiplier(1000);

  }

 function xMil(){
  multiplier(1000000);
 }
 function xBil(){
  multiplier(1000000000);
 }

 function xTril(){
  multiplier(1000000000000);
 }

 function xQuad(){
  multiplier(1000000000000000);
 }  

 function clr(){
 document.getElementById("input").value = "";
 document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = "";
 }

 
 </script>

  </head>

  <body>
 <div><p>Enter a large whole number (commas OK). </p></div>
 <input type="text" id="input"/>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Convert" onclick="convert()">
 <br>
 <input type="button" id="xthou" onclick="thou()" value="thousand">
 <input type="button" id="xmil" onclick="xMil()" value="million">
 <input type="button" id="xbil" onclick="xBil()" value="billion">
 <br>
 <input type="button" id="xtril" onclick="xTril()" value="trillion">
 <input type="button" id="xquad" onclick="xQuad()" value="quadrillion">
 <input type="button" id="clr" onclick="clr()" value="Clr"> 
 <br><br>
 <div><span id="commaed"></span></div>
 <br>
 <div id="converted"></div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `'32兆1312億0023万2132'.replace(/0+(23万)/g, "$1")`

Comment: I forgot to delete the n, thank you

Comment: have a look here. It seems to do what you want http://sebpearce.com/kazu/

Comment: @mplungjan fun interactive (and stylish link). I tried posting progress of my working app on the original post - couldn't get it to run like it does in browser... but When run properly goes beyond 億

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use capturing group.

```
string.replace(/(\D)0+/g, "$1")
```

`(\D)` captures a non-digit character and the following `0+` would match one or more 0's. Replacing the matched chars with the chars present inside the group index 1 will give you the desired output.

Comment: 23 could be anything.. no?

Comment: What does the plus sign do in this regex?

Comment: (@karthikmanchala yes i would like the number of 0's after one charcter before the first [1-9] digit to be variable {1,3}

Comment: @AvinashRaj your update works great! I have one question: why doesn't the replace method delete the `\D` in the process? is it the $1?

Comment: yep, `\D` was captured by the group index 1. `replace` function will replace all the matched characters . In our case, the matched chars are `non-digit` + 0's. And it captures that particular non-digit char. So `$1` in the replacement part will give you the captured char and leaving all the remaining matched chars.

Answer (score 0):

I find regex fiddles very helpful for this kind of thing. I made one here:
https://regex101.com/r/jG3aB5/1

I think the regex that will solve your problem is this one:

```
(?:[^0-9])*(0*)
```

It matches an arbitrary number of zeros that follow a single non-digit character. The non-digit character is not captured and will not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Use lookbehind to not include the match character `\D` but match only zeros. Please see the working [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX8bR6/5)

```
/(?!\D)0+/g
```

In your case:

```
myriad = myriad.replace(/(?!\D)0+/g, "");
```